# Is there any limit for fetching followers from twitter

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

Fetching the followers list of a user, but there might be some users that have millions of followers. So are we able to fetch all followers using twitter api.

Presently using users/lookUp api and followersId api to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a limit, around 5k(not exact as Twitter says) for each request.

You can use Twitter 'cursoring' technique as described here https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring

> The Twitter REST API utilizes a technique called ‘cursoring’ to paginate large result sets. Cursoring separates results into pages (the size of which are defined by the count request parameter) and provides a means to move backwards and forwards through these pages.

Each cursor has previous/next_cursor and other stuff that you can use when sending request. Check out the example provided in official documentation.

Comment: @Ch0k0i8 I want to ask can we get the lakhs or million of followers list, i know that we have to use pagination and that limits to 5000 and second api limits to 100.